# How can a TCP connection be closed by the remote during the TcpListener AcceptSocket?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have a service which listens for SSL connections. Recently experienced a problem where the TcpListener loop looked like it has stopped executing. We had imagined that it had something to do with the SSL handshake but that was fully logged with some catch all logging and nothing showed. After some changes and more logging I realize that the problem is not on the SSL connection but on the TcpListern.AcceptSocketAsync method. The exception is

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host.

My question is, how can the connection be closed during the AcceptSocketAsync method? I thought that the TCP SYN would hit the server and the code would complete the AcceptSocketAsync method. The TCP RST should only come into play on the next call to send OR receive on that socket.

Comment: The tcp handshake actually has 3 packets: client:SYN, server:SYN+ACK, client:ACK. Can you monitor the connection with tcpdump, wireshark or something else like these?

Comment: I've already seen some cases with a network load balancer involved, or duplicate IP addresses on the network. Network monitoring tools may help a lot.